# Display summary of cgrid view at bottom of grid

Tags: php, yii

I use CGridView in Yii to create tables. I would like to show my table with pagination, but display summary text (i.e. `Displaying 1-4 of 4 results.`) at the bottom of grid. Is it possible in Yii?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add this property to your array options widget:

```
'template'=>'{items}{summary}{pager}'
```

This is how it should look like:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'enablePagination' => true,
        'template'=>'{items}{summary}{pager}',
        'columns'=>array(...)
        ),
    ));
```

[Yii docs - CBaseListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#template-detail)

Comment: I think the OP's asking about how to change default placement of summary text of CGridView, not how to change its contents.

Comment: Changing the summary text is made by adding:
'summaryText' => 'My Grid is showing you {start} - {end} of {count} cool records',
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#summaryText-detail

Comment: Of course it is. But, read the question (and my answer) again. He is asking how to "_display summary text (...) **at the bottom** of grid_". There is no way you're going to force grid view to display summary text **at the bottom**, by just changing `summaryText` property. Without using own class, it will always be displayed over the grid (you can use CSS to move it to the left, if you wish, but no way, you're going to put it to the bottom this way).

Comment: template and summaryText are totally different grid options.
Template is for change the display position, so you can have the summary at the bottom of your grid.
The summaryText will replace the token {summary} in the template but you still can change the place where it is set in reference with the others 2 tokens available {items} and {pager}

Answer (score -2):

```
'template'=>"{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}"
```

Comment: Some explanation is called for.